# jQuery: .attr to href if DIV contains('text')?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, contains, attr

(Twitter) I am trying but not sure how to use this to **.attr** at beginning of **links/A/href**, if the element selected contains certain words:

```
 $(".tweet:contains('government','Anonymous')").each(function(){
   $old_url = $(this).attr('href');
   $new_url = 'http://blankrefer.com/?'+$old_url;
   $(this).attr('href',$new_url);
  });
```

This works but without text detection:

```
$("A").each(function(){
   $old_url = $(this).attr('href');
   $new_url = 'http://blankrefer.com/?'+$old_url;
   $(this).attr('href',$new_url);
});
```

Comment: Can you explain a little more what your problem is?

Comment: jfyi: `$("a").attr("href", function(idx, oldValue) { return 'http://blankrefer.com/?' + oldValue; });` does the same as your second example :) [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-function)

Comment: and using Andreas' example, you could use an if-contains inside the return function to return either the original or the amended url

Comment: it still doesn't work with word detection @andreas

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass multiple search strings to `:contains`, see [this](https://api.jquery.com/contains-selector/) for more information. You can repeat the selector with another search string using comma separator as shown below.

```js
$(function(){
     $(".tweet:contains('government'),.tweet:contains('Anonymous')").each(function(){
        $old_url = $(this).attr('href');
        alert($old_url);
        $new_url = 'http://blankrefer.com/?'+$old_url;
        $(this).attr('href',$new_url);
     });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="tweet" href="gov">government one</a>
<a class="tweet" href="ano">Anonymous one</a>
<a class="tweet" href="gov2">govern two</a>
```

Comment: something like this?  
**$(function(){
     $(".tweet:contains('Anonymous')").each(function(){
     $("a").attr("href", function(idx, oldValue) { return 'http://blankrefer.com/?' + oldValue; });
});**

Comment: after clicking on 'Run code snippet' button above you will get alert with href of matched links only. Why it is not working in your case? did I wrongly understand your problem?

Comment: check for console error on browser or recreate the problem on jsfiddle link and share it with me